# When I open Google Chrome on Windows 10, it crashes the system almost instantly, why?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, crash, troubleshooting, virus-removal

## TL;DR

When I open Google Chrome on Windows 10, it crashes the system almost instantly.

In detail: My laptop stops responding (freezes) and I can hear louder cooling (supposedly higher CPU usage due to system dump generation). Then, I long press the power button.

All other installed browsers (Edge, Internet Explorer, Firefox) work OK.

How can I debug this?

## Long version

I haven't used Windows in a month or so.

I work on Linux, but I have a Windows 10 too for Blu-ray playback mostly.

Current Windows 10 version:

```
1709 (OS Build 16299.248)
```

I have just manually installed the latest update from [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb4058258):

```
windows10.0-kb4058258-x64_69f87cf7f2ea83509d5e61ba2d525a103a6d64f9.msu
```

The installation was successful, although the problem persists.

I have also manually downloaded an updated version of Google Chrome and successfully installed it:

```
64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

I have also disabled Fast startup by setting the following registry key to `0`:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power\HiberbootEnabled
```

And checked the file system with:

```
chkdsk c: /f
```

How can I debug this?

---

**EDIT1:**

[image: Crash Dump I managed to view in Visual Studio 2015]

I tried Anonymous mode, the same result. Strange is, after some boot, it does not crash. I'm confused and irritated.

---

**EDIT2:**

I have just turned on [DEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection#Windows) not only for services but for everything:

[image: Data Execution Prevention]

It didn't have any effect, just tried it. Leaving it enabled.

---

**EDIT3:**

I cannot switch user profile, as it crashes instantly my OS. Though, I tried Anonymous mode, with the same result.

---

**EDIT4:**

I ran these commands with all good results, no corruption detected and such, from PowerShell:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

Afterward, I have scanned the OS with SFC utility for any violations. Again, no result.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> sfc /scannow
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.
Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

**EDIT5:**

As of this moment, I am scanning my system with [ESET Smart Security Premium](https://www.eset.com/int/home/smart-security-premium/), which I had installed since the system has been started using time-to-time, I have an SSD and a HDD, I will report back.

**EDIT6:**

I am still in progress with [ESET](https://www.eset.com/int/home/smart-security-premium/), but I have finished scan with [SpyBot 2.6 Free edition](https://www.safer-networking.org/mirrors26/), with no results, tracks only. I had this software installed since the same time I use Windows 10 with [ESET](https://www.eset.com/int/home/smart-security-premium/) too.

**EDIT7:**

[ESET](https://www.eset.com/int/home/smart-security-premium/) did not find any malware. I am now up to running [VIPRE Rescue](https://www.vipreantivirus.com/vipre-rescue-virus-removal-tool.aspx) over night in safe mode. Will get back to you tomorrow with results.

**EDIT8:**

[VIPRE Rescue](https://www.vipreantivirus.com/vipre-rescue-virus-removal-tool.aspx) did find 11 instances of malicious files. Removed 7 of them. Currently I'm looking for a good AntiVirus and AntiSpyware software, maybe better than [ESET](https://www.eset.com/int/home/smart-security-premium/) to run in trial mode or freeware tool to remove this mess.

**EDIT9:**

I have found several high quality solutions like [Bitdefender Antivirus Plus 2018](https://www.bitdefender.com/solutions/antivirus.html), which I have just purchased. Many others are running.

[image: CPU 99%]

As you can see, my CPU has a lot to do right now, I will get back.

Comment: open the dmp in Windbg.exe (part of Windows 10 SDK) and add **https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com** to symbol options and run **!analyze -v** to start debugging

Comment: the symbol servers should contain all PDBs for all versions released by google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my comment which started the poster on the right path:

> Try to :
>
> 1. run Chrome in Incognito mode
> 2. run it with the `--disable-extensions` command-line option.
>
> If either of these helps, then some extension is killing your
>   computer, maybe by mining cryptocurrency, or **in short you are
>   infected**.
>
> Try then to uninstall Chrome using Revo, and afterward scrub the disk
>   and registry for all remnants, then install Chrome again.
>
> **Antivirus deep scans may also help.**

Even if you think you have cleaned out all viruses, keep a very sharp
eye on how the computer is behaving.
Some viruses manage to stay alive and reinfect the computer.
The only sure way to clean it all out is to reformat the disk and reinstall
everything.

See also :

[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, my system had been infected with multiple threats. Not only a bad browser extension.

---

As of right now, I finished purging everything out (I hope). I used too many tools, but having a relatively strong CPU and a fast SSD drive helped a lot.

---

I admit it hasn't crossed my mind that I would be infected while having [VB100](https://www.virusbulletin.com/testing/vb100/) most awarded AntiMalware solution.

---

Namely, I will still be a customer of [ESET Smart Security Premium](https://www.eset.com/int/home/smart-security-premium/), but I have purchased a second solution, that being  [Bitdefender Antivirus Plus 2018](https://www.bitdefender.com/solutions/antivirus.html), which has proven to be highly effective.

---

Case solved. Many thanks to [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) for the suggestion, namely running Chrome with:

```
--disable-extensions
```

option, which had started it all.

Comment: ESET nor Bitdefender is an anti-malware product.  Malware is an entirely different beast when compared to a virus.  Malware is often used as a vector for other malicious infections, a virus, attempts to actually destroy your files either by removing them or encrypting them (aka Ransomware)